# Уточнение пространства имён enum-а

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Почему для return type надо уточнить какой enum

```
TestClass::ePower TestClass::GetPower()
```

, а для входного параметра нет?

```
void TestClass::SetPower( ePower _power )
```

при написании реализации вне класса ?

---

Весь hello world код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

enum class ePower
{
   other,
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class TestClass
{
public:
   enum class ePower
   {
      on,
      off
   };


private:
   ePower                                    power;

public:
   void                                      SetPower( ePower _power );
   ePower                                    GetPower();
};


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


void TestClass::SetPower( ePower _power )
{
   power = _power;
}


TestClass::ePower TestClass::GetPower()
{
   return power;
}


int main()
{
   TestClass a;
   a.SetPower( TestClass::ePower::on );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В соответствии с правилами поиска неквалифицированных имен, в частности, имена, используемые вне декларатора функции-члена класса, как, например, используемые в описании возвращаемого значения, ищутся в той области, где определен класс.

Имена, используемые в частности в деклараторе функции-члене класса, ищутся в области определения класса.

Поиск неквалифицированных имен для вашего примера описан в параграфах №7 и №8 раздела **3.4.1 Unqualified name lookup**  стандарта C++.

> 7 A name used in the definition of a class X outside of a member
>   function body, default argument, exceptionspecification,
>   brace-or-equal-initializer of a non-static data member, or nested
>   class definition29 shall be declared in one of the following ways:
>
> — before its use in class X or be a member of a base class of X
>   (10.2), or
>
> — if X is a nested class of class Y (9.7), before the definition of X
>   in Y, or shall be a member of a base class of Y (this lookup applies
>   in turn to Y ’s enclosing classes, starting with the innermost
>   enclosing class),30 or
>
> — if X is a local class (9.8) or is a nested class of a local class,
>   before the definition of class X in a block enclosing the definition
>   of class X, or
>
> — if X is a member of namespace N, or is a nested class of a class
>   that is a member of N, or is a local class or a nested class within a
>   local class of a function that is a member of N, before the definition
>   of class X in namespace N or in one of N ’s enclosing namespaces.

и

> 8 For the members of a class X, a name used in a member function body,
>   in a default argument, in an exceptionspecification, in the
>   brace-or-equal-initializer of a non-static data member (9.2), or in
>   the definition of a class member outside of the definition of X,
>   **following the member’s declarator-id**31, shall be declared in one of the 
>   following ways:
>
> — before its use in the block in which it is used or in an enclosing
>   block (6.3), or
>   — shall be a member of class X or be a member of a base class of X
>   (10.2), or
>
> — if X is a nested class of class Y (9.7), shall be a member of Y, or
>   shall be a member of a base class of Y (this lookup applies in turn to
>   Y’s enclosing classes, starting with the innermost enclosing class),32
>   or
>
> — if X is a local class (9.8) or is a nested class of a local class,
>   before the definition of class X in a block enclosing the definition
>   of class X, or
>
> — if X is a member of namespace N, or is a nested class of a class
>   that is a member of N, or is a local class or a nested class within a
>   local class of a function that is a member of N, before the use of the
>   name, in namespace N or in one of N ’s enclosing namespaces.

И сноска 31

> 31) That is, an unqualified name that occurs, for instance, **in a
>   type in the parameter-declaration-clause** or in the
>   exception specification.

Эти же правила дублируются и в других разделах, где описание относится к классам.

Comment: это в описании рекомендаций работы компиляторов или выдержка с стандарта?

Comment: @rikimaru2013 Поиск неквалифицированных имен для данного случая описан в параграфах №7 и №8 раздела 3.4.1 Unqualified name lookup стандарта C++.